# How can I conditionally add in a mixin to the current class on instantiation?

Tags: python, class, mixins

I'd like to have a class that adds in mixins based on arguments passed to the constructor. This is what I've tried:

```
class MixinOne(object):
    def print_name(self):
        print("{} is using MixinOne.".format(self.name))


class MixinTwo(object):
    def print_name(self):
        print("{} is using MixinTwo.".format(self.name))


class Sub(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        mixin = args[1]

        if mixin == 'one':
            bases = (MixinOne,) + cls.__bases__
        elif mixin == 'two':
            bases = (MixinTwo,) + cls.__bases__

        return object.__new__(type('Sub', bases, dict(cls.__dict__)))

    def __init__(self, name, mixin):

        print('In Sub.__init__')

        self.name = name
```

The only problem with this seems to be that `__init__` doesn't get called, so the `print_name` methods will not work.

1. How do I get `__init__` on `Sub` to fire?

or

2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `__init__` is only called if `__new__` returns an instance of the class.  Your on-the-fly class inherits from a mixin, and from `Sub`'s *parents*, but not from `Sub` itself.  It'll probably work if you set `bases = (MixinOne, cls)`.
2. Write a factory function (or classmethod) instead of overloading `Sub`'s construction.  Even better, just make some subclasses instead of creating classes at runtime.  :)

Comment: 1. That works. Thanks. 2. I have quite a number of mixins and a number of classes like Sub, the array of subclasses I'd have to manually write doesn't warrant this solution to be practical.

Answer (score 11):

This is a neat place to use metaclasses. You can put the custom-mixin-inclusion code in the meta, then your `Sub` classes don't need to have the boilerplate:

```
class AutoMixinMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            mixin = kwargs.pop('mixin')
            name = "{}With{}".format(cls.__name__, mixin.__name__)
            cls = type(name, (mixin, cls), dict(cls.__dict__))
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class Sub(metaclass = AutoMixinMeta):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now you can create `Sub` objects and specify the mixin as follows:

```
>>> s = Sub('foo', mixin=MixinOne)
>>> s.print_name()
foo is using MixinOne.
```

It'll automatically get pulled out of the kwargs dict so the `__init__` method can remain completely unaware of its existence.

---

Note: the metaclass declaration syntax in Python 2 is slightly different:

```
class Sub(object):
    __metaclass__ = AutoMixinMeta

    def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
```

Comment: Nice solution. I went with the quick fix in Eevee's answer, but may refactor to use this. Thanks.

Comment: I can't get the above code to work. I get a **TypeError** ```__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mixin' ```. I tried adding `**kwargs` to the `__init__` method but without success

Comment: @drstevok are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.1. Here's the code https://gist.github.com/docsteveharris/7693d78e235b0d354cdc5b56ef264280 in case I made a typo

Comment: @drstevok that would be it then. Python 3 doesn't look at the `__metaclass__` attribute, instead you need to provide it in the declaration. Try `class Sub(object, metaclass = AutoMixinMeta)`

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you. That fixed it.